# How to convert select max sql query to eloquent laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have sql query for select max data from database in laravel controller. But, I want to use the eloquent version for doing that.

This is my sql query

```
DB::select('SELECT saldo
        FROM akun_trxes
        WHERE akun_id IN (SELECT id FROM akuns WHERE akun_parrent = 1)
        AND id IN (
            SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM akun_trxes
            GROUP BY akun_id
        )');
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (not tested)

```
        AkunTrxs::select('saldo')
            ->whereIn('akun_id', function ($query) {
                $query->select('id')
                    ->from(with(new Akun)->getTable())
                    ->where('akun_parrent', 1);
            })->whereIn('id', function ($query) {
                $query->selectRow('MAX(id)')
                    ->groupBy('akun_id');
            })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 AkunTrxs::select('saldo')
            ->whereIn('akun_id', function ($query) {
                $query->select('id')
                    ->from('akuns')
                    ->where('akun_parrent', 1);
            })->whereIn('id', function ($query) {
                $query->selectRaw('MAX(id)')->groupBy('akun_id');
            })->get();
```